# Service reference: Custom Tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType

Tags: silverlight, wcf, linq, wsdl, porttype

This is in relation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273662/saving-image-to-database-as-varbinary-silverlight/8273687#8273687), which I think might be caused by this problem.

I added a new service to add a varbinary to my database table: Afbeeldingen

- id:int
- afbeelding1:varbinary(max)

I made the service contract like this:

```
[OperationContract]
public void setAfbeelding(Afbeelding a)
{
    dc.Afbeeldings.InsertOnSubmit(a);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I compiled the project, added the service reference to my main project and then I get the following errors:

```
Custom tool warning: Unable to load one or more of the requested
types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='']/wsdl:portType[@name='EditAfbeeldingService']

....
```

[image: service reference errors]

I managed to fix this, by adjusting the reference like explained [here](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2010/11/25/custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdl-porttype.aspx).
But I don't think this is healthy and I think it is now causing me isseus with what I'm trying to do. ('OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.Binary' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments, is the error I'm getting)

I really hope somebody can help, silverlight and WCF have been one big mess for me so far..
Thank you in advance,
Thomas