# Saving image to database as varbinary (part 3)

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, image, varbinary

This is yet again a problem I have with saving images in silverlight to my database, I thought I had it all working untill I tried it out with a different image...

I save images to my database with following method.
I first convert the image to an array of `byte` and then send it to my service.

```
 private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //nieuwe instantie van de klasse "Afbeelding", om later door te sturen naar service
            Afbeelding a = new Afbeelding();

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG files|*.jpg";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                //Afbeelding ophalen via open dialoog
                Stream stream = (Stream)openFileDialog.File.OpenRead();
                string fileName = openFileDialog.File.Name;

                //Converteren naar bytes
                //byte[] bytes = BinaryConverter.convertToByte(stream);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

                //aan de instantie de Binary waarde van de afbeelding meegeven om naar de database te sturen
                a.id = 1;
                a.source = new Binary { Bytes = bytes };
            }

            EditAfbeeldingServiceClient client = new EditAfbeeldingServiceClient();

            client.UpdateAfbeeldingCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_UpdateAfbeeldingCompleted);
            client.UpdateAfbeeldingAsync(a);
        }
```

And in my service I do this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    public void UpdateAfbeelding(Afbeelding a)
    {
        var query = (from p in dc.Afbeeldings 
                     where p.id == a.id
                     select p).SingleOrDefault();

        query.source = a.source;
        dc.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

Now during my testing this all worked, but I only used one image to test... 
So when I tried just now with a different image, I get the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. In Silverlight, a 404 response code may be reported even when the service sends a different error code. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.EditAfbeeldingServiceClient.EditAfbeeldingServiceClientChannel.EndUpdateAfbeelding(IAsyncResult result)
   at OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.EditAfbeeldingServiceClient.OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.EditAfbeeldingService.EndUpdateAfbeelding(IAsyncResult result)
   at OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.EditAfbeeldingServiceClient.OnEndUpdateAfbeelding(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

I can't really read anything out of that error so once again, I'm stuck here.
I apologise for using these boards so much, but I really wouldn't if it wasn't needed so much.

I have set the maximum to send through to a high number, but it still doesn't work.

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
maxArrayLength="2147483647"
maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

You can find my web.config here: http://pastebin.com/whMs5h1w

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.
Thomas

Edit: I managed to get a more readable error with enabling tracing, hope this helps anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

WCF has various limits built in. One is the `maxReceivedMessageSize` which is 65536 bytes by default and another one is `maxArrayLength` (not sure what the default is). There is a good chance you have exceeded one of the two (or both). You can change those in your service configuration. [This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx) contains some example configurations.

Also [enabling tracing for your service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) might provide you with some more insight of which limits are hit.

Btw: There is a [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) method.

**Edit**: Apparently there is a tool called [Fiddler](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/03/31/silverlight-and-wcf-essentials-fiddler/) which can help tracking these issues down.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do? I can't save images to my database with WCF?

Comment: @ThomasSchoof: No, you need to increase the limits in your config. Sorry, made it clearer in the answer.

Comment: I already had to increase the maxArrayLength because of a previous error I got, and that one stated I had to enlarge it. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275398/saving-image-to-database-as-varbinary-arraylength-part-2/8275697#8275697)

And I could just use the File.ReadAllbytes method to convert the image to an array of byte?

Comment: @ThomasSchoof `ReadAllBytes` does not convert anything. It just reads the file content into a byte array, same thing you are doing in your code right now.

Comment: Thank you, but what am I supposed to do with sizes? I already increased them with `<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880"/>`

And it does not work, or is that nog long enough?

Comment: @ThomasSchoof If you already increased them then they are probably not the problem. Try enabling WCF tracing and Fiddler.

Comment: I really have no idea what I'm doing with all the debugging, I enabled WCF and installed Fiddler but it doesn't really tell me anything...
This is getting way out of my league

Comment: I increased the max of nearly everything to the maximum but I'm still getting the same error:                     `<readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />`

Comment: Try enabling tracing (server side), as ChrisWue suggested; the traces on the server will have some information why the request was rejected.

Comment: I just did so, I editted the error I am getting, thanks for the help so far :) I appear to be a getting a [protocol exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907249.aspx)