# binaryMessageEncoding cannot contain child element

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, web-config, varbinary

This question has to do with my previous question where I get errors trying to save `varbinary` to my database through a web service.

I increased the `maxArrayLength` etc.. to send through to the server which works like this (in `web.config`):

```
<binding name="OndernemersAward.Web.Service.EditAfbeeldingService.customBinding0">
    <binaryMessageEncoding>
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

    </binaryMessageEncoding>                  
    <httpTransport />
  </binding>
```

But when I try to do this in my `ServiceReferences.clientconfig`

```
<binding name="CustomBinding_EditAfbeeldingService">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
  </binding>
```

I get the following error:

> The element 'binaryMessageEncoding' cannot contain child element 'readerQuotas' because the parent element's content model is empty.

I'm just trying out things to try and fix the error I'm getting in my previous question, because I'm getting quite desperate. :P

I hope somebody can help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no reader quotas in Silverlight (in other words, they're all already max'd out), so your config is equivalent to the one below:

```
<binding name="CustomBinding_EditAfbeeldingService"> 
  <binaryMessageEncoding/> 
  <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/> 
</binding>
```

Comment: Thank you, so that can't be the problem in the error I'm getting in my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280423/saving-image-to-database-as-varbinary-part-3/8280538#8280538) then?

Comment: Correct, this isn't the problem. I'll post a comment in the other question as well.